# Internal Server Error when adding lines to htaccess for increasing upload size limit

Tags: wordpress, upload

I'm following [this tutorial](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/increase-memory-limit/?mkpp=b&utm_expid=3606929-97.J2zL7V7mQbSNQDPrXwvBgQ.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2F) to increase default WordPress upload size limit by adding lines to the htaccess file. This is my file before modification:

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_4

Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mosquee-mirail-toulouse.fr$
RewriteRule ^(.*)   /$1 [QSA,L,R]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The tutorial says to add these lines at the very end of the htaccess file:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
php_value post_max_size 2000M
php_value memory_limit 3000M
php_value max_execution_time 180
php_value max_input_time 180
```

However when I do that, the site stops working and I get a blank page instead that says "Internal Server Error". Why?

Comment: Go check the error log, it will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried yo edit php.ini File?
You can access this with ftp and add this to your code.

Comment: Yes that's the first thing suggested by the page I linked: creating a php.ini file in wp-admin folder containing upload_max_filesize = 1000M post_max_size = 2000M memory_limit = 3000M file_uploads = On max_execution_time = 680. Didn't work.

Comment: Create a file in root folder of website,not in wp-admin

Comment: @ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '12M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '13M');
@ini_set( 'memory_limit', '15M' );
You can add this in wp-config file

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, have you tried editing your php.ini file through root access via an FTP programme such as Filezilla?

1. Go to:  File>Site Manager>Protocol:  SFTP - SSH File Transfer Protocol
2. Enter your Root Login Credentials.
3. Head to:  /var/www/vhosts/system/[site-name]/etc
4. Here you should find a file entitled:  php.ini
5. Download this and enter and open in a programme such as Notepad++.
6. Simply enter your values, within the file.  Save and then upload to the same directory.

If your php.ini file is not in the location I suggested:

1. Create a file called and entitle it: phpinfo.php
2. Insert the code:   and save the file.
3. Upload the file to your public_html directory
4. Then head to http://yourdomain.com/phpinfo.php
5. Look for a row entitled:  Loaded Configuration File and follow the directory for the location of the php.ini file.

I have had problems with editing my .htaccess file, in this fashion, before.  I make my modifications, using the above steps and have not come across any problems.

Hope this help you!

Comment: It's a shared host, I don't have access to these folders... I did create a php.ini in my wp-admin folder to no avail.